# Finding cdf of variable that is the cdf of another variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

$X$ is a continuous r.v. with cdf $F_X(x)$, $Z$ is a r.v. defined as $Z = h(x) = F_X(x)$.

I need to find the cdf of $Z$, namely $F_Z(z)$.

I know that
$$
F_Z(z) = P(Z \leq z) = P(h(X) \leq z) = P(F_X(x) \leq z) = P(P(X \leq x) \leq z)
$$
but I am unsure how to proceed to find an expression for $Z$'s cdf with the information given.

Comment: No, $P(h(X) \leq z)$ is not $P(F_X(x) \leq z)$, but $P(F_X(X) \leq z)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:

$F_{Z}(z)=P(h(X) \leq z)=P(X \leq h^{-1}(z))=h(h^{-1}(z))=z$

And one has that $Z \sim U(0,1)$ (clearly, $Z$ takes values between $0$ and $1$). This is known as the probability integral transformation. We can take inverses since $F$ is increasing (for the case where $F$ is not necessarily strictly increasing, this is neatly discussed here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209998/proving-the-probability-integral-transform-without-assuming-that-the-cdf-is-stri).

Comment: U is Uniform? Well Z takes values between 0 and 1 but I don't see why Z is uniformly distributed

Comment: $Z$ will have the same CDF as $U(0,1)$. If $z \geq 1$, $F_{Z}(z)=1$ and on the other hand if $z \leq 0$, $F_{Z}(z)=0$. I don't know if I'm missing something simple.